# Remove border from alt text if image url is not valid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, vb.net

Today is friday and this is a fun question (and a real problem). I am using border around the image but if the image url is not valid, the border appears around the alt text and looks kind of ugly. How to remove it using CSS?

```
<a href="#">
   <img src="http://badsrc.com/blah" style="border:1px solid black" alt="Remove border from this alt text" />
</a>
```

I don't want to overkill it with server side script or jQuery. Interested in CSS. If no CSS solution is available then other solutions are welcome.

My actual server side script looks like this

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(photoURL) Then
   photoUrl2="<img src="..." style="border:1px solid #000" alt="BMW for sale">"
end if
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DV4LG/)

Comment: friday hmm!, okay, give it a black background and a white color  and it's gone ;)

Comment: How cum? jsfiddle? :) That means black border will be gone from images as well if image is a valid url. Wont solve the problem

Comment: style="border:1px solid #000;background:#000;color:white"  it's a silly friday answer ... i go 86  heu, nop border stands outside o(

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ayEwz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use onerror and set the border

```
<a href="#">
 <img src="http://badsrc.com/blah" onerror="this.style.borderWidth=0" style="border:1px solid black" alt="Remove border from this alt text" />
</a>
```

It would be better to not use inline styles and use classes

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es5ER/)

Comment: That add the border onload, there is no way to speed it up. OR have the server check to see if it is a valid file.

Comment: is `onerror` javascript. Can you give a demo? It did not work for me.

Comment: unfortunately, none of the solutions work in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**.error()**](http://api.jquery.com/error/), it binds an event handler to the "error" JavaScript event.

```
$("img").error(function () {
    $(this).css('border', 'none');
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/DV4LG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting it via server side, the correct thing to fix this *on* the server side, not in CSS or JavaScript.  All you have to do is change your code to this:

```vb
photoUrl2 = String.Format("<img src='...' style='border:{0}' alt='BMW for sale' />",
                          If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(photoURL), 
                             "none", 
                             "1px solid #000"))
```

Comment: the photo url does exist! It just sometime may not point to a valid photo and alt text will appear.

Comment: I see.  This would still be a good server side change in the case that the url didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#">
 <img  id="myImage" src="http://badsrc.com/blah" style="border:1px solid black" alt="Remove border from this alt text" />
</a>

<script>
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage'); // or select based on classes
    image.onerror = function(){
      // image not found or change src like this as default image:
       image.style.border = "none";
    };
</script>
```

here is your solution with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old question but here is CSS only solution using pseudo elements

```css
img:after {  
  content: attr(alt);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
 <img src="//placehold.foo/200x200" alt="Remove border from this alt text" />
```